# \textrecipe does not work with xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode

The code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
\textrecipe
\end{document}
```

works properly generating unicode character `(U+211E)` But when I add \setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003} downloaded from here [Sanskrit 2003.zip](http://www.omkarananda-ashram.org/Sanskrit/sanskrit2003.zip) , it fails to generate the unicode character. This may be related to availability of symbol in font or for some other reason, but I need to retain both the symbol and font in the document. Kindly help.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{wasysym}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003}
\begin{document}
    \textrecipe
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The package `wasysym` has nothing to do with `\textrecipe`. The command is defined in standard LaTeX by the `textcomp` package, which is not to be loaded with XeLaTeX and `fontspec`.

The problem is that the Sanskrit 3000 font has no glyph for `℞` (U+211E PRESCRIPTION TAKE) so `\textrecipe` produces nothing (with XeLaTeX a small square is drawn).

You can substitute the missing character with one from a font that has it, for instance Asana Math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Sanskrit2003.ttf}
\newfontfamily{\presc}{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newunicodechar{℞}{{\presc ℞}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\textrecipe}{℞}}

\begin{document}
R℞R

R\textrecipe R
\end{document}
```

Note that the Latin glyphs in Sanskrit 3000 seem to be very similar to Palatino.

[image]

Comment: Great choice of font. Maybe you print some `R\textrecipe R` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your font does not provide this symbol ([here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/211e/fontsupport.htm) is a collection of fonts, which do). Therefore, you will have to redefine this command in order to use an other font for this very symbol:

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Sanskrit2003.ttf}
\renewcommand{\textrecipe}{{\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"211E}}}

\begin{document}
    Choose some font you like: 
    {\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"211E}}{\fontspec{freeserif.otf}\symbol{"211E}}{\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"211E}}{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"211E}}

    Redefine the old \verb|\textrecipe|.

    Use it in text as \textrecipe{} before.
\end{document}
```

[image]