# I would like to insert "℞" in a regular latex document

Tags: symbols, unicode

I tried searching searching but couldn't come across any.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218194/197451

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\textrecipe does not work with xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218191/textrecipe-does-not-work-with-xelatex)

Comment: `textcomp` package provide directly to insert “℞”: the command is `\textrecipe`.

Comment: The textcomp package looks like a very direct way to implement it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TS1 encoding support this character:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textrecipe}{TS1}

\begin{document}
Recipe: \textrecipe
\end{document}
```

[image: Recipe LaTeX]

Answer (score 2):

Like this for instance (the value for the kerning has to be adapted to the font):

```
\textsf{P\kern-3.5pt{\scriptsize x}}
```

[image]